# I am trying to send email programmatically in C# but I don't find what I am missing. Here is the code for the same

Tags: asp.net-mvc

`A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [::ffff:40.99.9.50]:587"

Code Is

```
try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("email");
        mail.To.Add("email");
        mail.Subject = "Subject";
        mail.Body = "Message";
        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email", "password");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);`
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "false";
    }
```